# "Could not load question; loading in browser instead"

Tags: support, badges, android-app

If click on an earned badge in my achievements using the Android app, some of them will open up the browser, but just showing the "index" page of the  linked exchange site. I'll receive the message:  ** "Could not load question; loading in browser instead"**

With" some badges" I mean those not linked to a question e.g. Autobiographer or linked to removed questions, comments etc.

That's annoying, why can't the app just show me that page in the app without opening the browser? Because the app specifically asks me how to open that link and choosing the Stack Exchange App to do so won't change the result.

Is this really intended?

I am using Android version 5.1.1 and Stack exchange app version: 1.0.89